# Google sheets python API - module 'google.auth.credentials' has no attribute 'CredentialsWithTokenUri'

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client, google-auth-library

I'm trying to set up the Google Sheets API for python. When I run the [quickstart.py](https://github.com/googleworkspace/python-samples/blob/main/sheets/quickstart/quickstart.py) file (exactly as specified in the google documentation), I receive the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'google.auth.credentials' has no attribute 'CredentialsWithTokenUri'
```

I've followed the instructions from https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python.

Installed the necessary packages, created a project in the Google Cloud console, enabled the sheets API, filled out the `OAuth` consent, created credentials, saved the `credentials.json` into my working directory.

I'm unable to run Python `quickstart.py` or Python 3 quickstart.py - I receive the error each time.

I'm not sure what the error means or where to start. Any help is appreciated?

Full error message below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/heshimuntiu/Desktop/scripts/googleSheetsAutomation/quickstart.py", line 5, in <module>
    from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
  File "/Users/heshimuntiu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .interactive import get_user_credentials
  File "/Users/heshimuntiu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/interactive.py", line 27, in <module>
    import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
  File "/Users/heshimuntiu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 68, in <module>
    import google_auth_oauthlib.helpers
  File "/Users/heshimuntiu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/helpers.py", line 27, in <module>
    from google.auth import external_account_authorized_user
  File "/Users/heshimuntiu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/auth/external_account_authorized_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    credentials.CredentialsWithTokenUri,
AttributeError: module 'google.auth.credentials' has no attribute 'CredentialsWithTokenUri'
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe they changed something in module and maybe you use old code or you have to update module.

Comment: Just edited to include the full error message. Thank you @furas
The module is updated. It's possible that quickstart.py file from the website isn't up to date, but this is my first time using this library so I'm not so familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: update to Python 3.10+.

As of Jan 2024,
the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) you mentioned states:

> Prerequisites: Python 3.10.7 or greater, ...

I checked which version of Python I run.
I have exactly the same error on `Python 3.9.2` and *no error* on `Python 3.10.11`.